# Remote Desktop remembers a very old version of the desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When using Remote Desktop to connect from WinXP to Win2k3 I often encounter the following: when I minimize and then restore the RD window it shows a very old version of the remote machine desktop and then refreshes i and shows the current state. What is more strange - it doesn't show the state that was there when I minimized the window, but instead it shows the very same very old state each time I minimize/restore. It's very annoying.

Is this known behaviour? How can it be worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, try to delete the profile and try it again. Maybe something on that profile got all messed up. If you log on to the server with that profile does it do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed this, but I haven't bothered investigating. Its just not that big an issue.